# convert sys.stdout.write to print in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a python code with the following code :

```
sys.stdout.write("{}\t".format(leaf_distances[n][m]))
```

I just wondered if someone knew a way to replace `sys.stdout.write` by a `print` argument ?
So far I tried:

```
print("{}\t".format(leaf_distances[n][m]))
```

but it does not seem to be the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent is `print` that does not add a line break at the end of the output. New-style formatting:

```
print(f"{leaf_distances[n][m]}\t", end="")
```

Old-style formatting:

```
print("{}\t".format(leaf_distances[n][m]), end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want

```
print(str(leaf_distances[n][m]), end="\t")
```

for an equivalent.